# When adding a value from an input field to the database to an existing number, the number added is double

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

When the inputted number for $points is taken in the inputted field, it adds the number to the total already in the database, but for some reason the number added is double. For example if input 3, 6 will be added to the total. Can anyone help with an answer to this?

The idea is that someone should be able to add points to the total, and then on a separate page able to view it in a progress bar (which is working correctly) but the totals do not add up.
I am new to php so sorry in advance for any mistakes throughout the code.

Thank you

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
    header("location:login.php");
} else {
echo "Userid: ".$_SESSION["sess_id"];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<h2><a id="button" href = "index.php">Main Menu</a></h2>
<h2><a id="button" href = "selftrack.php">Track your updated progress!</a></h2>
</head>
<body>

<?php
            // Connect to the database
            $username = ""; 
            $password = "";
            $host = "";
            $db = $username;
            $points = $_POST['self_p'];
            // Connect to the MySQL server and select the required database
            $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

            if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            } 
            else { // Database connected correctly            

                echo "<h1>Add  daily points</h1>";
                if (isset($_POST["addSubmit"])) { 
                    if ((!empty($_POST["self_p"]))) {// Check all parts of the form have a value


                        $query="UPDATE targets 
                        SET self_points = self_points + ".$points."
                        WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['sess_id']."'";


                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                        if ($result == false) { 
                            // Show error message
                            echo "<p>The target points for  " . $_POST["self_p"] . " was not added.</p>";                        
                        } 
                        else { 
                        echo "<p>The target points for \"" . $_POST["self_p"] . "\" has been added.</p>";
                        }
                    } 
                    else { 
                    echo "<p>Please fill out all the details</p>";
                    }
                }
            }

            ?>

            <form  role="form" id="addForm" name="addForm" action="?" method="post">            

                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <label for="addFormLast_Name">Please enter your daily points, up to 5:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="addFormLast_Name" name="self_p" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <input class="form-control" id="addSubmit" name="addSubmit" value="Add Target" type="submit">

                </div>
                </div>
                 <?php
             mysqli_close($connection);
        }
        ?>
                </body>
                <?php

?>

                </html>
```

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code related to the addition, but your query is open to SQL injection attacks. Make the points value a parameter instead of inserting it directly in the query. Google "PHP parameterized query" to see how to do it.

Comment: For some reason using the $points variable added double, changed it to use the $_post and it seems to be working fine now... weird! Thank you for the advice

Comment: There must be something else at play here. Change it back to `$points` and see if it will work this time.